# assigning permission to flatpages

Tags: python, django, permissions

I need to assign a permission to flat pages  like about-us . I have no models for it , I simply installed flatpages and accessed it from url.py. There are options like django-guardian and django-authority but I have already started my project with django basic permission.

can it handle flat page permission?

Comment: Have you read the docs on django-authority?

Comment: yes i did... i know it won't hamper existing permission :)

Answer (score 0):

No, django's default permissions setup can only handle model-level permissions - eg, giving users access to all flatpages. For row-level permissions - like assigning permissions only to the about-us flatpage - you need to use something like django-guardian or django-authority.

Django-authority's docs actually show integration with flatpages as an example:

http://packages.python.org/django-authority/create_custom_permission.html#create-a-custom-permission